# Getting and Setting values in java 8 using optional and map

Tags: spring-boot, java-8, option-type

I am trying to use Optional instead of standard null checks in java

```
@Data
public class InputObj {
    private Double savings;
} 

@Data
public class Result {
    private String outputSavings;
}

public Result convertInputObjToResult(InputObj inputObj){
    Result result = new Result();

    Optional<InputObj> optionalInputObj = Optional.ofNullable(inputObj);

    optionalInputObj.map(InputObj::getSavings).map(value -> util.convertRoundAndAbs(value,true)).ifPresent(result::setOutputSavings);

    return result;
}
```

which is equivalent of below

```
public Result convertInputObjToResult(InputObj inputObj){
    Result result = new Result();

    if(inputObj != null){
               if(inputObj.getSavings() != null){ 
        result.setOutputSavings(util.convertRoundAndAbs(inputObj.getSavings(),true));
    }    

    }

    return result;
}
```

I wrote some test cases and I do not get any Null Pointer Exception but I am unable to understand that ifPresent condition is at end and map is before but still I don't get any NPE. Do you see any thing wrong with this code or how it can be improved? This is part of a spring boot application and @Data annotation is used for lombok.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here's [a link to further describe how the map operation works](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) for the Java Optional class.

> If a value is present, apply the provided mapping function to it, and if the result is non-null, return an Optional describing the result. Otherwise return an empty Optional.

So in a case where you have a null value from the `map` method, it will automatically be converted to `Optional.empty()`.

Then, taking a [look at the ifPresent method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#ifPresent-java.util.function.Consumer-)

> If a value is present, invoke the specified consumer with the value, otherwise do nothing.

So this is why you aren't getting any NPE's; the map operations are able to map `null` results **or** passed values to `Optional.empty()`, and the `ifPresent` operation doesn't execute if passed an empty Optional.

Answer (score 0):

There is no issue with the code except for the typo “ optionalMembershipDetails”. Assuming you meant to use “ optionalInputObj”.
You need to read about java streams to understand the full concept. In a nutshell, operations are evaluated in lazy manner. So ifPresent call will trigger operations which appear before it. In this case, the object is wrapped inside optional, so each intermediate operation will pass another optional to the next operation. Having Optional prevents you getting NPE.

Comment: I updated the typo. The operations are evaluated in lazy manner but ifPresent triggers evaluation of map, now the input to map can be null right? @bluesky33 is commenting that map can take care of null values. I believe I can replace the last ifPresent with another map and that should also work.

Comment: Input to map is not null, it is an Optional. You can think Optional as a wrapper object, where the underlying object could be null, but the Optional itself is not null. Map on Optional converts the optional object to another optional, by changing underlying object. So you won’t get NPE. You can use as many maps you want in same pipeline.